How can you force a blocked mq_receive call to give up?
I am trying to upgrade a messaging library from SYSV message queues to POSIX message queues.  Unlike with SYSV queues, closing and/or deleting a POSIX message queue that is blocked in mq_receive() does not unblock it, causing my programs to hang.  I have also tried setting the O_NONBLOCK flag on the message queue's attributes, but that does not seem to have an effect when set while it's already blocked.
How can I force a blocked mq_receive() to give up and return?
Note that using mq_timedreceive() or setting the O_NONBLOCK attribute beforehand is not an option.  I am updating a library used by existing applications which expect the message queue to unblock in this scenario.  The OS is Linux.  The only idea I've come up with so far is to send empty messages until it unblocks.  But this seems a bit hacky, and leads to a new question: How can you detect if the queue is currently blocked so you'd know to do this?

Prior to calling mq_receive, use sigaction to install a signal handler for an otherwise-unused signal, e.g., SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, or one of the real-time signals. The function doesn't have to do anything; just the fact that one gets called at all is all you need.
When you're ready to force mq_receive to return, send it the signal that you installed the handler for. It will then return -1 and set errno to EINTR.

Upvoted -- for most situations, this is right answer.  Unfortunately, my library is used in highly multi-threaded applications and there is just no way to guarantee that the signal will end up in the right thread.

@Haydentech Can't you use tgkill to make sure the right thread gets it?

At the time when the port is closed, how would the thread which is closing the port know what other threads are currently blocked on that descriptor?  I'm sure an expert in signals and multi-threading could probably pull it off, but it would be messy.  I found my solution below to be small and self-contained at least.

Although you mentioned that using non-blocking behaviour was not an option, perhaps it is worth exploring whether you can avoid getting into the blocked-on-mq-receive situation at all ?
On Linux, the mqd_t descriptor of the POSIX queues is pollable, which means you can write a trivial "peek" function to determine whether there is anything in the queue before you call mq_receive().
More details at mq_overview if you scroll down to Linux implementation of message queue descriptors.

This is a library, so I can't really control the order in which the methods are called.  Your answer does help for another problematic method in the library though.  I need to block (with the ability to timeout, just like mq_timedreceive) until a message comes in, but without actually reading the message.  Hopefully select() or poll() will do the trick there.

If you are implementing this library (from wording of your original question, I've assumed you are) then you simply make your new receive() library function do the "peek" step first, and depending on the outcome, call mq_receive() - or not. In the case where the peek finds nothing ready to receive, you bail out with an error code to the caller, or deliver an empty message, or both, depending on your needs. Note that your receive() calls could still be blocked if more than one thread is calling them...

That doesn't solve the problem case, which is that the caller is legitimately waiting on a message (i.e. wants to block in mq_receive) and then the port is later closed/deleted by another thread before a message comes in.  Peeking doesn't help, because at the time mq_receive happens, the close/delete hasn't happened yet.  On top of that, I can't change the API anyway.

mq_receive and mq_timedreceive only check for a closed file descriptor at the moment they are called, and never after.  So the trick is to make multiple calls.  Calls that should block indefinitely, which would normally use mq_receive, are transformed into a loop of mq_timedreceive calls that timeout once per second and are retriggered indefinitely.  This guarantees at most one second of wait time to break out of a hung call that would otherwise never return.
It's not the prettiest solution in the world, but it works and avoids the multi-threaded signal delivery problems of the other answers.  Below is what I used to replace mq_receive calls.  A similar but slightly more complicated version is required to replace mq_timedreceive calls, since in that case you have 2 layers of timeouts.
struct mq_attr attr, oldattr;
struct timespec ts;
size_t bytesReceived;
int priority;

construct_posix_timespec(&ts, timeout);

attr.mq_flags = O_NONBLOCK;
if (mq_setattr(id, &attr, &oldattr) == -1) {
    printf("mq_setattr failure\n");
}

do {
    bytesReceived = mq_timedreceive(id, (char*)msg, attr.mq_msgsize, &priority, &ts);
} while (bytesReceived < 0 and errno == ETIMEDOUT);

if (mq_setattr(id, &oldattr, NULL) == -1) {
    printf("mq_setattr failure\n");
}

